# Search for a number after a keyword in long string

Tags: python, regex

I search a very long string for a couple of keywords and want to extract the number that is listed after them.

My Code below works if the keyword is standing alone and not connected with another word as seen here (`temperature/melting`) and the second problem is the `°` sign after the number.

I need a general solution because there can always be different words attached/linked to the keyword.

```
import re

keywords = ["temperature", "humidity", "pressure"]
txt = "Lorem Impsum temperature/melting point: 370° C don't ...."
# it works if the string is as followed
#txt = "Lorem Impsum temperature /melting point: 370 ° C don't ...."

for l in range(len(keywords)):
    ResSearch = re.search(keywords[l], txt)
    if ResSearch != None:
        list_txt = txt.split()
        print(f"{ResSearch} \n{list_txt}")
        try:
            j = 0
            while True:
                    try:
                        j += 1
                        next_number = int(list_txt[list_txt.index(keywords[l]) + j])
                        print(f"Number after Keyword: {keywords[l]} is {next_number}")
                        break
                    except Exception as r:
                        print(r)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic use case for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

keywords = ["temperature", "humidity", "pressure"]
txt = "Lorem Impsum temperature/melting point: 370° C don't ...."

for keyword in keywords:
    match = re.search(f"{keyword}.*?(\d+)", txt)
    if match:
        print(f"Number after Keyword: {keyword} is {int(match.group(1))}")
```

`.*?` will match any string that follows the `keyword` (`"/melting point: "` in this case), and `\d+` will only match one or more digits (0 to 9).

this will print

```
Number after Keyword: temperature is 370
```

Comment: I got another issue now. If the txt is `Zündquellen fernhalten. Nicht rauchen. P243` and my keyword is `r.h.` it finds a match. I found out why, (14 pos. is an `r` and 16. pos an `h`, so it seams like the `.` in my keyword are like placeholder?). Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: That's not the reason. Dot (`.`) is a wildcard character, so `r.h.` is actually matching `rnha` in `fernhalten`. Try escaping the dot i.e. `r\.h\.`.